# Powershell guid is not unique when I run it in multiple threads - How can I make it unique?

Tags: powershell, guid, uid

I am running a script in powershell in multiple threads (multiple shells), and I'm finding that its possible for the NewGuid powershell function to generate values in powershell 7 that are not actually unique when run at the same time.

`"${env:TEMP}\some_unique_file_$([guid]::NewGuid()).json"`

The above can produce a conflict when I'd like each string here to be unique.  Is there something missing or is this a bug?  It's almost as if PID is not considered when generating a GUID.

for further context, its also possible because its defined as a parameter default, that this is causing the issue:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string]$houdiniEnvFile = "${env:TEMP}\some_unique_file_$([guid]::NewGuid()).json"
)
```

Comment: Without seeing your code is impossible to tell whats wrong. Certainly, no such thing as a duplicate GUID

Comment: [While the probability that a UUID will be duplicated is not zero, it is generally considered close enough to zero to be negligible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Without more details (as a collision rate), I tend to believe what @Santiago implies: you probably doing something wrong (as your expression should at least be quoted). Anyways, you might simply use the [`New-TemporaryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-temporaryfile) cmdlet for what you trying to do.

Comment: You need to surround the string with double-quotes and also expand the `.Guid` property: `"${env:TEMP}\some_unique_file_$([guid]::NewGuid().Guid).json"`

Comment: @Theo, explicitly  referencing the `.Guid` property is _not_ needed in a string-interpolation context, given that `.ToString()` is implicitly called when stringifying an object; try `"$([guid]::NewGuid())"`. Also, if the expression is used _as a command argument_, double-quoting - while advisable - isn't strictly necessary. I think we need more information to find the true cause of the problem.

Comment: @iRon the New-Temporary file command is excellent, thankyou. however I'm interested in getting a shared ID for a number of unique directories and files eventually.

Comment: Before coming with a possible solution, it is imparitive to understand what is happening here first. In my believing you need to create so many files from all the sides to be able create a guid collision that it is more likely that you creating a kind of [Denial-of-service (DoS) attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) on the concerned file server. So how did you determine it is a guid conflict, do you get a specific error? Did you capture the conserned guid/filename to prove it is conflict?. Does it really exist already?

Comment: Hello @iRon, when I checked the logs for unique files being produced I could see sometimes each file was the same.

Comment: If you really want to investigate the (high?) rate of of collisions, please [add these details to thre question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76050850/edit): when was the guid generated? (afaik, as the is a time component in the guid you can only create a collision at exactly the same time), examples of the collided path/guid. Rate: how often does the collision happen? A ***complete*** [mcve] to be able investigate and reproduce the initial suggested issue.

Comment: Btw the loosely definion `"${env:TEMP}\some_unique_file_$([guid]::NewGuid()).json"` already shows a weird train of thought. What does  `some_unique_file_` represent? Why not just a verbatim (or no) prefix? (knowing that the `guid` should already be unique.) In other words, you appearently not giving us the full story that proves you really encountered a guid collision.

Answer (score -3):

Theo is right. You have to expand the property Guid. NewGuid() creates an object with a single property. And to get to the value, this single property has to be expanded.

That will look like this:

```
${env:TEMP}\some_unique_file_$([guid]::NewGuid().Guid).json
```

Another possible approach is:

```
${env:TEMP}\some_unique_file_$((New-Guid).Guid).json
```

It is as fast, but maybe a little bit easier on the eyes ;)

Comment: Explicitly  referencing the `.Guid` property is _not_ needed in a string-interpolation context, given that `.ToString()` is implicitly called when stringifying an object; try `"$([guid]::NewGuid())"` or  `"$(New-Guid)"` - in outcome your commands are equivalent to the command in the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).